# Where is data stored when using an HTML 5 Web SQL Database

Tags: html, web-sql

I just read something about HTML 5 Web SQL Databases.  I did a little search on here and Google but couldn't find a simple to the point answer.

Can someone tell me, where is the data stored when using this?  In memory or a text file or something else?

Also what browsers support this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's stored in a SQLite database. [Here](http://caniuse.com/sql-storage) is a browser support chart I found: .

That said, the W3C has officially dropped support for WebSQL in favor of IndexedDB. [Here's](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb) the equivalent chart for that:

You may also want to look at [DataJS](http://datajs.codeplex.com/), which is a library that abstracts some of the details of local storage and works across browsers:

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links I will read up some more.  I just found this page http://www.webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/index.html which is really cool demo app using WebSQL for a simple note app.  It's a shame you said they are dropping support

Comment: You can build the equivalent type of app with IndexedDb and it's arguable that this is a better abstraction for the web than WebSQL (though I don't want to get into that debate here :)). If you don't mind, could you mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 22):

Web SQL locations by system for **Google Chrome**:

**Windows Vista or 7**

```
\Users\_username_\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
```

**Windows XP**

```
\Documents and Settings\_username_\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
```

**Mac OS X**

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases
```

**Linux**

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases
```

Comment: Safari:  ~/Library/Safari/Databases/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one browser example:

On Windows 7, Chrome stores Web SQL (aka SQLite) databases in:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases`

Each extension or website that uses Web SQL is given its own folder. Within each folder will be a numbered, extensionless file that is an SQLite database. You could open said file with [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) or any SQLite-supported application.

Answer (score 0):

And in case anyone is looking for IndexedDB:

On **Mac OS X**:

**Chrome**

- `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/IndexedDB/<site>.blob` (`Blob` storage)
- `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/IndexedDB/<site>.leveldb` (everything else - just LevelDB)

**Firefox**

- `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile>/storage/default/<site>/idb`