# Where does Chrome's extensions store data?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Under OSX Google Chrome extensions are stored in `~/Library/Application Suppert/Google/Chrome` but where does the extensions store their data?
I need to export settings from my previous osx installation

Comment: If you want to export your settings, just copy the whole profile directory. Visit `chrome://version` and look at "Profile Path" (minus the trailing "/Default").

Comment: Yes, but I need only a single extension data, more specifically Page Monitor extensions data. I accidentally deleted it and I have a backup of the entire OS :/

Comment: It depends very much on what APIs are used, e.g. chrome.storage, localStorage, Web SQL, IndexedDB, filesystem, cookies, .... The source code of https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/ogeebjpdeabhncjpfhgdibjajcajepgg shows that it uses WebSQL at the very least (so look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8510241). If you copy the profile directory for your backup, disconnect internet (to avoid updates) and then start Chrome with that profile directory, then you can use the devtools to inspect the various databases. Or just ask the extension author for help.