# where did Pouchdb save the attachments to our local pc ? which folder can we check it?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

[i am a fresher on pouchdb.  i save a file to my local pc by using the demo code:

```
        var db = new PouchDB('todos');
        var attachment =
        "TGVnZW5kYXJ5IGhlYXJ0cywgdGVhciB1cyBhbGwgYXBhcnQKTWFrZS" +
        "BvdXIgZW1vdGlvbnMgYmxlZWQsIGNyeWluZyBvdXQgaW4gbmVlZA==";
    db.putAttachment('this0058089', '55ee5.txt', attachment, 'text/plain').then(function(result) {
        // handle result
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

which folder can we check the file we save? or how can we check it?

this is my project, i found no file i saved.
[image]
this is my storage, it's empty.
[image]

Comment: pouchDb uses indexedDB to store data in the browser, so to check the storage , in Chrome you would go to - Dev tools Inspector > Resources > IndexedDB.

Comment: I checked , but i found the storage is empty, but i have saved some files.

Comment: you are correct, i finally find it in the indexedDB folder in the above img,   thanks your information, Dylan .

Comment: [Here is some information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36341491/680742) on where Chrome/Firefox stores data in IndexedDB.

Comment: thanks guys, can you add your comment in answers? so i can flag it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pouchDB acts as an adapter to communicate with your browser's native in browser database(it can be IndexedDB, Web SQL etc).  In the case of chrome browser the data will get stored within the 'IndexedDB'.

You can go to 'Developer Tools -> Resources -> IndexedDB' to inspect the data stored.