# Where is my data? Using PouchDb and Electron...nowhere to be found

Tags: indexeddb, electron, pouchdb

I am beginning to experiment with PouchDb and electron.  I was successfully able to create an input that stores my data.  I can then retrieve my data and display in my view.

I would like to know where my data is being stored.  I tried deleting all my history including automatically and manually deleting my IndexedDb data from my browser but my data remains.  I have also tried removing all LocalStorage from the browser.  I am totally unaware of where my data is being stored if it is not being handled by the browser's IndexedDb.  Any pointers??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This varies from adapter to adapter. If you use the LevelDB adapter (recommended for Electron), then you can specify the filepath just as if you were using it in Node.

If you use IndexedDB or WebSQL, though, then it could be in a lot of places. For Chrome, though, I did hunt it down, so hopefully this answer helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341491/680742. Also in the case of Electron, this might actually be in `~/Library/Application Support`, can't quite recall. Good luck!

Comment: I'll give this a gander when I get some more time.  Thanks for answering and keep up the great work!  I'll repost when I find out where it may be hiding...

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the data is may be stored under `~/.config/$YOUR_APP_NAME`.